# How do I format an R table in an R Jupyter notebook?

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-irkernel

Suppose I am using a Jupyter notebook with an R kernel, and I want to format a table so that any row with p_value < 0.01 is bolded.  How?

I [looked](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1182) around a bit, and I can find R styling not in Jupyter, Jupyter styling not in R, and so forth, but not what I want.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about this approach?

```
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(IRdisplay)

mtcars %>%
  kable("html") %>%
  row_spec(which(mtcars$mpg > 20), bold = T, color = "red") %>%
  as.character() %>%
  display_html()
```

[image]

Comment: When I add `display_html` I get "Error in display_html(.): could not find function "display_html". When I try to load `IRdisplay`, I get " namespace ‘IRdisplay’ is imported by ‘IRkernel’ so cannot be unloaded".

Comment: @abalter Hmm, that's unexpected. I just tried and it still works for me. Do you want to try `... %>% as.character() %>%
  IRdisplay::display_html()`

Comment: I inadvertently arrived here again, and this time your suggestion worked!