# formattable in R shows data type name in header

Tags: r, formattable

I'm printing a dataframe in R, using "formattable". I'm executing it in a Jupyter notebook with an R kernel.
Here the code:

```
df = data.frame(
     Return = percent(accumulReturn[selcol,1]),
     AnnualizedReturn = percent(annualizedReturn[selcol,1]/100),
     MonthlyReturn = percent(annualizedReturn[selcol,2]/100),
     Vola = percent(volatilityTable[selcol,1]),
     Sharpe = round(annualizedReturn[selcol,1] / 100 / volatilityTable[selcol,1],2),
     Drawdown = percent(dds)
 )

t <- formattable(df)
t
```

In the headers of the columns it shows the data type of each column, which is very distracting. I don't want to see the data type there. How can I do it?

I tried using different formatters, but they seem to get ignored by the function call.

Comment: HTML output from an R function to a Jupyter notebook may need a tweak like `display_html' (package IRdisplay). Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46531571/how-do-i-format-an-r-table-in-an-r-jupyter-notebook#46532394 ?